# Passing parameters to Stored Procedure without @ symbol

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

Well, Im curious what will happen if i pass some parameters without `@` symbol

```
public static int Run(string command,string anotherParameter, DataTable dt)
 {
   SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SPName", Connection.Connect);
   adapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
   adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@command",SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value=command;

   //another one without @        
   adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("anotherParameter",SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value=anotherParameter;
     try
        {

            return adapter.Fill(dt);
        }
     catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        finally
        {
            adapter.Dispose();
        }     

 }
```

this may run sometimes and failed another?

Thanks

Comment: did you try this code? What exactly error you have got

Comment: @Mido Fairly certain we have some code that specifies `@` and some that doesn't. Both work.

Comment: @Garath well, i tried it yes, but i noticed that it works sometimes and sometimes not.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't add `"@"` before parameter name, the `"@"` is added automatically.But good practice is to manually add `@` and do not rely on automatic functionality.
See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.parametername.aspx for more information